# How does isInstanceOf method work in Scala?

Tags: java, scala

I am running the below code in Scala 3.x. As per my understanding it should have returned True, because Int extends AnyVal as per Scala documentation.

```scala
scala> val y = 20
val y: Int = 20

scala> y.isInstanceOf[AnyVal]
1 |y.isInstanceOf[AnyVal]
  |^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |cannot test if value of type Int is a reference of class Object
```

In Java, the below code prints true, which is understandable.

```java
class A {}

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        System.out.println(a instanceof Object);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is because `isInstanceOf` leaks the erasure of the **Java** runtime platform. Neither `Int` nor `AnyVal` exists at runtime, they are compile-time concepts, but `isInstanceOf` is a runtime operation that does not work with types but with classes. In any case, normal **Scala** code must never call `isInstanceOf` anyways.

Comment: scala> val x:AnyVal = 10
val x: AnyVal = 10

why does below code return True ?

scala> x.isInstanceOf[Any]                                                                                                   
val res0: Boolean = true

Comment: Int is primitive type, but can be automatically wrapped to Integer or to RichInt. You can't use `20 instanceOf Object` in Java either.

Answer (score 0):

In Scala, this is typically done using `match`

For example, to check the type of `y` (cast as an `AnyVal`), you could do something like:

```scala
val y: Int = 20

val yAsAnyVal: AnyVal = y

yAsAnyVal match {
    case long: Long => println(s"Y is a Long! $long")
    case int: Int => println(s"Y is an Int! $int")
    case char: Char => println(s"Y is a Char! $char")
    case _ => println(s"Y is not a Long/Int/Char")
}
```

Prints:

> Y is an Int! 20

---

Scala 3: Match Expressions (Syntax) - https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/changed-features/match-syntax.html

Scala 3: Match Expressions (Examples) - https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/changed-features/pattern-matching.html